# Paragraph ended before \align*

Tags: latexit

I need help learning how to use LaTeXiT.

I keep getting the following error, no matter what I try (be it different codes, or very basic "hello world" codes).

```
Paragraph ended before \align* was complete.
```

Can anyone help me at least learn how to start off with this? I've tried looking online, but I couldn't find anything that helped.

This is what I've typed:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

This is my first LaTeX document.

\end{document}
```

But the "preamble" has:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: you would not get that error from the posted document, you have an `align*` environment with a blank line between `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}`

Comment: Hi and welcome, are you really compiling this example? Maybe LaTeXit compiles a different document.

Comment: @David Carlisle, I don't know what you mean by "environment". I'm new to this, literally downloaded this about an hour ago. I never included \begin{align*} and \end{align*}.

Comment: presumably the system is not processing the document that you think it is processing, since the error message is about `\begin{align*}`

Answer (score 1):

LaTeXiT doesn't require any preamble (`\begin{document}` and so forth);  all of the preamble stuff that the LaTeX engine is expecting is automatically prepended to your input.  You just put the code in that you want typeset.  So if you want to typeset `Hello World!`, you just need to put `Hello World!` into the dialogue box.

If you want to mess around with the preamble that LaTeXiT prepends to your code, go to Preferences > Templates.  (Edited:  upon further reading, I see that you found this stuff already, but I figured I'd explain what it was.